# HTML not being parsed in tag description for search

Tags: bug

It looks like the description for the search tag is being escaped, or not properly parsed, but only when performing a more complex search containing a tag, and other values.

For example, this is broken.

[Search Term: "[c] answers:0 closed:0 score:1-9"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%5d%20answers%3a0%20closed%3a0%20score%3a1-9)

[image: Broken]

But other basic searches work:

[Working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=newest)